# Web2py database locks with a large table

Tags: sql, web2py

I have a table with 100 fields and created 100 users. When I create the first record of user 1's table, everything is normal but when I create a second table record, the databases slows the server too much that the website does nor render. I noticed that creating the first records for all 100 users does not slow things but it is the second record that messes everything up.
I was thinking it could be my database inquiry that has issues but I double checked and did not find anything unusual. My inquiries are based on the logged in user's id and I use that to render table rows on the website.

Comment: can you show sample data (maybe 5 columns), your inquiry, and your expected result?

Comment: I found the answer for it:As your number of users grows; sqlite's simple locking strategy will lead to increasingly great lock contention, and you will need to migrate your data to another database, such as MySQL (Which can do row level locking, at least with InnoDB engine) or PostgreSQL (Which uses Multiversion Concurrency Control). If you anticipate that you will get a substantial number of users (on the level of say, more than 1 request per second for a good part of the day), you should migrate off of sqlite; and the sooner you do so, the easier it will be.